# Any result connecting an NP-complete problem with slight super-polynomial time?

Tags: polynomial-time, np-complete

Helo everybody,

> is there any result or research that connects some $NP$-complete problem
>   with only *slightly* super-polynomial (strongly sub-exponential) time?

This would not necessarily involve the $P$ vs $NP$ problem (which i stand on $P=NP$, anyway).

Thank you

Comment: huh, why not? P≠NP follows QED

Comment: @vzn, not necessarily if it does not provide separation between P and NP, for example a result that an np-complete problem can be solved in slightly super-polynomial time, does not exclude a polynomial algorithm

Comment: oh you mean an _upper_ bound?

Comment: @vzn, yes it can also be an upper bound, or an actual algorithm that runs in slightly super-polynomuial time, both do not exclude polynomial algorithms. If you are interested, check this [other question of mine](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/24879/easier-and-harder-instances-of-np-complete-problems)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might need to be more specific as to what "slightly super-polynomial" means. But, this might work: you can take an NP-complete problem, and pad it.

For example: for any constant $k\ge 1$, $n$-vertex instances of CLIQUE remain hard when only $n^{1/k}$ of the vertices have positive degree (e.g., take an instance $G=(V,E)$ of CLIQUE and add $|V|^{k}-|V|$ isolated vertices to it). These instances of CLIQUE can be solved in time $2^{n^{1/k}}\text{poly}(n)$.

Comment: +1, ahh nice, assume this is *very slight super-polynomial*. Indeed the exact *threshold* of *slight* super-polynomial is not specified. Intuitively it is super-polynomial but sub-exponential, the exact threshold is part of the question itself. Will wait for other answers also

Comment: So as $k$ tends to infinity, it becomes polynomial, correct?

Comment: In the meanwhile, if you would like to elaborate a little more on how the $2^{n^{1/k}}+ \text{poly}(n)$ complexity is computed for this CLIQUE problem, or add some reference would be very nice.

Comment: The naive algorithm is to remove all isolated vertices and then try all possible subsets of the $n^{1/k}$ remaining vertices.